# Replace for loop - R Script

Tags: r, for-loop

Is there any way to replace the `For loop` in the code below by `Apply` family function or represent it in any other way to speed up the code execution:

```
line = strsplit(textFileContent, " ")
for(i in 2:n){ #looping from 2nd line to nth line of an input txt file

  a = as.numeric(line[[i]][1]) #starting index in a matrix
  b = as.numeric(line[[i]][2]) #ending index in a matrix
  k = as.numeric(line[[i]][3]) #a number

  mat[1,a:b] = mat[1,a:b] + k
  #mat is a matrix of 5 zeros.
  #mat = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. 
  #Each time a value (k) will be added to all the elements between starting and ending index
}
```

**EDIT**

**Sample input(textFileContent):**

5 3

1 2 100

2 5 100

3 4 100

Here, 1st line of the input contains 2 space separated number. 1st number says that the `mat` matrix will initially contain 5 zeros. 2nd number says how many lines follow the first line. In the above code it is taken as `n`.

Next lines contain 3 space separated numbers. 1st is `a`, 2nd is `b` and the 3rd is `k`.

*N.B.: The values of a, b, k, n and 1st line's 1st number may vary.*

**Output:**

[100, 200, 200, 200, 100]

**Modified code**

```
filepath = "C:\\textFileContent.text"
con = file(filepath, "r")
inp1 = readLines(con, n = -1, warn = FALSE)

line = strsplit(inp1, " ")

matadd<- function(line) {
  a<-as.numeric(line[1])
  b<-as.numeric(line[2])
  k<-as.numeric(line[3])
  mat[1,a:b]<<-mat[1,a:b]+k
}
mat<-matrix(0,nrow=1,ncol=as.numeric(line[[1]][1]))
temp<-sapply(line[2:(as.numeric(line[[1]][2])+1)],matadd)
cat(apply(mat, 1, max))
close(con)
```

With the sample input provided above the `line` looks like this:

```
> line
[[1]]
[1] "5" "3"

[[2]]
[1] "1"   "2"   "100"

[[3]]
[1] "2"   "5"   "100"

[[4]]
[1] "3"   "4"   "100"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data for `textFileContent`. Also what's value of `n` are you using in above `for-loop`?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but this will probably start you off:

    `sapply(line,"[",1:3)`

This will give you a matrix where the first row is your a, the second your b and the third your k (you might want to transpose it using `t()`).

Comment: Please see the Edit section for sample data.

Comment: I updated my answer with a fuller solution.

Comment: Did you make an error in your sample output? Shouldn't it be 100, 200, 200, 200, 100? column 5 gets added 100 only in the second round...

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a guess, but if I got your request and your data structure correctly, this should work:

```
matadd<- function(line) {
  a<-as.numeric(line[1])
  b<-as.numeric(line[2])
  k<-as.numeric(line[3])
  mat[1,a:b]<<-mat[1,a:b]+k
}
# Create the matrix with all zeros
mat<-matrix(0,nrow=1,ncol=as.numeric(line[[1]][1]))
# sapply the function on rows 2 thru end of the list
sapply(line[2:(as.numeric(line[[1]][2])+1)],matadd)
```

actually I could've just used the `length` of the list, come to think of it...

For example, with `line<-list(c(5,2),c(2,3,5),c(1,4,2))`, this is the result:

> > mat
>
> ```
>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] 
>
>  [1,]   2    7    7    2    0
> ```

Comment: I have modified my code with what you mentioned but it is getting runtime error for some cases. However, I don't have the access to check the inputs for which it is getting runtime exception.

Comment: Will be hard to figure this out without a sample file. Can you share what the first few items on `line` look like?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the 'cat' line? With the example you provided, my code works fine on my system.

Comment: The web portal where I am executing the code does not pass the code if the output has the auto generated row index number. For example, `[1] 200` is treated wrong, it should be only `200`. Hence I am using `cat`.

Comment: My best guess would be problems with the data. Try adding this after you create `line`: `sum(sapply(line,length)!=3)` if this equals more than 1, then you have lines with fewer or more than 3 items in them (except for the first one), which will throw an error. Also, add this: `sum(sapply(line,"[",c(1:2))[,-1]>line[[1]][1])` - if the answer is greater than zero, then you have rows where a or b is greater than the number of columns in the matrix, which will also throw an error.